# Is There a Better Way to Count the Number of Columns in an Access Database Table?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, jet-engine

I need to count the number of columns in a Table in an Access Database.

The following code does the job, but I wonder if there is a better way using  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ?

```
CmdStr = $"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [RoundData]";                                                                              
ReadCmd = new OleDbCommand( CmdStr, ResultsReportingOleDbConnection );
Reader = ReadCmd.ExecuteReader();
int NbrColumns = Reader.FieldCount;
```

Comment: As you aren't reading any data, you could add `WHERE 1 = 0` so that the query doesn't waste time reading anything beyond the schema.

Comment: Access doesn't implement `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` - instead you get `MSysObjects` - but _frustratingly_ it only exposes top-level objects and not any details of your columns. But you _can_ get at that kind of schema information if you use the (outdated and horrible, but somehow still works) DAO API: use `TableDef.Fields`. But my recommendation to you is to ditch Access and switch to _anything_ else seeming as Access' SQL implementation is stuck in pre-1992 years according to the ISO specs...

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Dai. Unfortunately the database I am interfacing to is either an Access 2000 database, or its an Access 75 (!!!) database, which is used by the 3rd Party Application to which I am interfacing. Is there any s/w package that will read an Access database that supports INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Comment: There is no Access 75, I think you mean Access 95? If so, that would be a JET 3.0 database - I don't think those are even supported at all on current versions of MS Office.